# c++11: why is static_assert in std::forward necessary?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

In move.h, there're two overloads of `forward`

```
template<typename _Tp>
constexpr _Tp&&
forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type& __t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t);
}

template<typename _Tp>
constexpr _Tp&&
forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&& __t) noexcept
{
    static_assert(
        !std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp>::value,
        "template argument substituting _Tp is an lvalue reference type"
    );
    return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t);
}
```

I see the `static_assert` is to prevent accidently casting a rvalue to a lvalue. Can the rvalue version be implemented this way:

```
template<typename _Tp>
typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&         
forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&& __t) noexcept
{
    return __t;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an example as to why it is dangerous to forward an rvalue as an lvalue, see use case C of [N2951](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html).  This use case shows how doing so makes it easy to create dangling references.

Answer (score 7):

It prevents strange things like `std::forward<std::string&>(std::string {})`.

The behaviour is mandated by §20.2.3p2:

> if the second form is instantiated with an lvalue reference type, the program is ill-formed.